# What is the best way to create forms in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade

What is the easiest, most elegant and effective way to create forms with Blade in Laravel 5.4? I'm creating an application with many forms and most of the fields look the same:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

@if ($errors->has('name'))
<ul>
    @foreach($errors->get('name') as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
```

So I wonder if there is any built-in mechanism to generate forms easily?

Thanks

Comment: I'd create separated file and parameterized it, then use `@include` and pass values... or you could take a look at `Form::model()` from laravelcollective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use the [Laravel Collective Forms & HTML Package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html) for [form model binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#form-model-binding) and [generating fields](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#text)
2. For displaying errors, you can use [sub-views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: Why this package is not include since 5.4 ?

Comment: While this is an option I don't believe it should be described as "The Best Way". As this package is no longer part of Laravel core I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @Lee I agree, the best way is always dependent on the application. That's why I have listed the two options that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my package:

https://github.com/netojose/laravel-bootstrap-4-forms

An amazing form generator based on Bootstrap 4 theming

Answer (score 0):

You could also use route model binding and pure HTML forms as an option.

Answer (score -1):

php composer.phar require laravelcollective/html